# Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs() is missing in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim` does not have `Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()` definition. I have an existing project that I am migrating to .Net Core. Everything else is working fine with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim` except I have a code snippet that contains `Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()`.

Intellisense shows below information:

> CS1061    'HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetQueryNameValuePairs' and no extension method
>   'GetQueryNameValuePairs' accepting a first argument of type
>   'HttpRequestMessage' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

Can anyone suggest how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct answer, but on the current request you can get the query string like this: HttpContext.Current.Request.Query. This gives you a parsed version of the query string as an IQueryCollection.

Comment: Will try that and confirm, thanks!

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.Query is the one :)

Comment: I'll put it as the answer then if you wanna mark it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you a parsed version of the query string as an IQueryCollection:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Query
```

Comment: AFAIK, this will only work if you host thru ASP.NET. If you self-host, it will break.

Comment: `Current` does not seem to be in the `HttpContext` library anymore. Any suggestions for replacements?